# How to make an image descend onto the screen on Activity onCreate using Canvas?

Tags: android, animation, canvas

I am a beginner to android app development and to using the Canvas in particular. Here is a picture of the title screen to an app I am currently working on:

[image]

What I would like to happen is to have the image of white game board to descend downwards from the top of the screen to where it is currently located now using animation through the Canvas. I am not exactly sure how I could do this, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Make this Game Board as an object of a class . Give it velocity variable, positions, methods for updating it's values a.s.o.

Then call frequently from a thread the update method(s)

All my bitmaps belong to objects

I have a Base class called DrawableObject

This class has

float posX, posY, velX, velY;
Bitmap bmp;

and several getter and setter.

This class is an abstract class.

It has also the method

public abstract void updatePos (long delTime);

I call it from a thread where I compute the time between two frames and pass the delta time to this method to update it's position for the time since last frame.